# Getting divider line between 2 mirror

Tags: mirror

Im making a simple model. I have added subsurface and mirror modifier. Im getting a divider or partition line between 2 mesh. I have on the clipping and merge in the panel. How can i dissolve the divider or partition line between. Any suggestion. Thanks **(Please do not tag duplicate plz reply with comment or answer)**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try increasing the clipping limit

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos can you tell how it is duplicate question and i have request not to make it duplicate tag so plz answer with my model. Thanks

Comment: @atek This site is not just for fixing models. It is for you to learn *how* to do it yourself. If your question is marked as a duplicate, go to the duplicate, understand what the answers there say, then fix your model. If you have any problems, come back and ask a specific question about that issue or post a comment asking for clarification on another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has 2 origins: the simpler is that the subsurf modifier should be after (down) the mirror modifier. The harder is that the mirror modifier uses as mirror pivot point the origin of the object, and your mesh is not in line with the axis. You can  solve the issue in this way:
switch to top ortographic view (toggle <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>5</kbd>); rotate your mesh until is quite aligned with the axis; in edit mode select the center line and scale it on the x axis by 0 (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>); put the cursor aligned with this edge loop (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>, cursor to selected, then - in object mode - set origin to 3D cursor); select the edge loop next to the central one and dissolve it (<kbd>X</kbd>, dissolve edges).
It's always a good practice to mantain the origin of the object in the center of the scene during the modelling phase, then move objects to the desired position.

[image]