# Local/Global Scaling?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, scale

I Have this line right in the cleavage of a character that I'm modeling, and I am using a mirror modifier to create her.

I was given a tip to reset the "middle" circle of vertices (The ones that are the closest to the mirror/Y Axis) by pressing "S" then "Y", "Zero" and then "Enter", but when I do this, it resets the entire action, because the "Local" "Zero" is where I started scaling from, whereas I want it to move to the "Global" "Zero".

[Her chest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qtdf.png)
[image: in edit mode]
[image: front view wireframe]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird line in my mirrored mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh) or [Subsurf and mirror modifier creating a split in mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh/6064#6064) or [Getting divider line between 2 mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73762/getting-divider-line-between-2-mirror)

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Cursor to Center (alternative to 1+2: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
3. <kbd>.</kbd> to change to Pivot Cursor
4. Scale your thing