# Mirror modifier and shading issues

Tags: normals, mirror-modifier

I’m new to Blender.

With the ear picture below, what do I do about the ring around the ear? Also with the head I can’t seem to figure out how to get rid of the line going down the face after I mirrored it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] link below your post, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Comment: hello please shareyour file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/why-does-the-mirror-modifier-sometimes-give-me-an-overlapping-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52181/weird-line-in-my-mirrored-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73762/getting-divider-line-between-2-mirror